# Get value of node in MS Access using JSOn

Tags: json, ms-access, firebase-realtime-database, vba

I am using [VB-JSON](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html) parser to get data from an API and saving the data in MS access table.

I am not able to figure out how to access the  `-KLj9kXnKd-9txfyIqM8` and `-KLjJoT7gXCMq_jHx2_z`.

I have Table structure as below, and want to save the data as shown below.

```
|ServerID               |Name       |Mobile
|-KLj9kXnKd-9txfyIqM8   |Adarsh     |9987
|-KLjJoT7gXCMq_jHx2_z   |Manas      |022
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "-KLj9kXnKd-9txfyIqM8": {
    "personmobile": "9987",
    "personname": "Adarsh"
  },
  "-KLjJoT7gXCMq_jHx2_z": {
    "personmobile": "022",
    "personname": "Manas"
  }
}
```

**VBA**

```
Public Sub GetPerson()
'I have code here which gets the json as above from api.     
Dim egTran As String    

If reader.Status = 200 Then
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblPerson", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

    egTran = "[" & reader.responseText & "]"
    Set coll = Json.parse(egTran)

    For Each contact In coll
        rs.AddNew
        rs!Name = contact.Item("personname")
        rs!Mobile = contact.Item("personmobile")
        rs!ServerID  = contact.Item("??????")
```

> what do I write in `??????`

```
        rs.Update
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

I am also open to using any other parser. The API is based on [Firebase Database](http://firebase.google.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VB-JSON, but obviously "??????" is not an item of *contact*.

Thus, if I run this test function:

```
Public Sub TestJsonText()

    Dim DataCollection      As Collection
    Dim ResponseText        As String

    ResponseText = _
        "{" & _
        "  ""-KLj9kXnKd-9txfyIqM8"": {" & _
        "  ""personmobile"": ""9987""," & _
        "  ""personname"": ""Adarsh""" & _
        "  }," & _
        "  ""-KLjJoT7gXCMq_jHx2_z"": {" & _
        "  ""personmobile"": ""022""," & _
        "  ""personname"": ""Manas""" & _
        "  }" & _
        "}"

    If ResponseText <> "" Then
        Set DataCollection = CollectJson(ResponseText)
        MsgBox "Retrieved" & Str(DataCollection.Count) & " root member(s)", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Web Service Success"
    End If

    Call ListFieldNames(DataCollection)

    Set DataCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

using the Json modules from [VBA.CVRAPI](https://github.com/CactusData/VBA.CVRAPI.git) it will print:

```
root                        
    -KLj9kXnKd-9txfy        
        personmobile        9987
        personname          Adarsh
    -KLjJoT7gXCMq_jH        
        personmobile        022
        personname          Manas
```

From the function *ListFieldNames* you can pick *MemberName* for the *field name* and *DataCollection(Index)(CollectionItem.Data)* for the *field value* to add records.